# Promise returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope, es6-promise, synchronous

In my code I try to assign a value to `json` variable to return it after (because I can't return it from the anon. function).

As my function is async, because it sends requests (maybe someone knows how to make it sync? I didn't plan to make it asynchronous), I've added `await` before the request (`https.get`).

I've been trying to get value from the Promise, but it's always `undefined`, even though I've awaited the async function.

Here's a code:

```
async function get_users() {
    const https = require('https');
    var token = '...';
    var json = undefined;

    await https.get('...', (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        resp.on('end', () => {
            json = JSON.parse(data)['response']['items'];
        });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

    return json;
}

get_users().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I searched for a bit and don't think `https.get` returns a promise. `await` will not wait for the request to finish.

Comment: The problem is that `json` is undefined when I return it. What's the reason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call is the issue - your await will finish once the current execution environment finishes its tasks, instead of when the request finishes.

Comment: So what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Return a `Promise` and `resolve` it, when the `end` event is called, otherwise `reject` it in case of an error occurred:

```
async function get_users() {
  const https = require('https');
  const token = '...';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get('...', resp => {
      let data = '';

      resp.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      resp.on('end', () => {
        let json;

        try {
          json = JSON.parse(data)['response']['items'];          
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        };
        resolve(json);
      });
    }).on("error", err => reject(err));
  });
}

get_users().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: This blows up when `data` cannot be parsed as JSON. You should do only `resolve(data);` in the end callback, and do any processing in promise `then` callbacks or after `await` where exceptions will be properly handled.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you! If you would want to process the `data` in the `get_users()` function, what would be the best approach in this case in you opinion?

Comment: `return new Promise(…).then(data => JSON.parse(data)['response']['items']);` or `const data = await new Promise(…); return JSON.parse(data)['response']['items'];`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my below code.I had issues with getting responses from Promises too.But i finally got it to work.Here's the code:

```js
var output;
var rp = require('request-promise-native');
var myJSONObject = {
  "inputs": [{
    "name": "<name>",
    "value": < value >
  }]
};
var orchName = 'TEST05';
postData = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject);
return networkCall(postData, orchName).then((response) => {
  console.log('response is' + response)

}).catch((response) => {
  console.log(`ERROR: ` + response);
});

function networkCall(postData, orchName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      method: 'post',
      uri: '<URL>',
      body: postData,
      auth: {
        'user': 'usr',
        'pass': 'pwd'
      },
      json: true
    };
    return rp(options)
      .then(body => {
        var response = body;
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('FAILED' + err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

This way your code can run in Synchronous Flow.If the return value is `undefined`,then,what  might have probably happened is that the calling function would have finished executing even before the called function returns its response.But the above approach would work just fine.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!